# How to create a project to import a UI qml interface into other applications

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I have a project that uses a server/client feature. My project layout is:

- Project w/ subprojects
- -server
- --- some files (not important)
- -client display
- ---Display.qml --> Main view
- ---ViewerForm.ui.qml --> UI Display to create the view
- ---Viewer.qml --> To run button clicks and javascript

I am able to run the server and client with no problems. Now, I would like to have the `Viewer` and `ViewerForm` to be available for different applications. For example:

1. Standalone client application (just the client display)
2. Imported into another application which may have several kinds of UI pages in which one is the client display.

How can I set this up so that I have only 1 `Viewer` project and it can be imported into different applications. Should this be a Qt Plugin? Module? I looked at the [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-cppplugins.html) and I created a `ViewerPlugin` project as it's own project with the `ViewerForm.ui.qml`, `Viewer.qml`, several component `*.ui.qml` and `*.qml` files, and javascript files as shown below. When I build the `ViewerPlugin` it creates a `Viewer` folder with files: `ViewerPlugin.dll`, `ViewerPlugin.exp`, `ViewerPlugin.lib`, and `qmldir`. Then, I copy this folder into my client application and import the QML plugin in my Display.qml like `import Viewer 1.0`. But I get build errors that it can't find: CListView.qml and the other qml files.

`viewerplugin.pro`

```cpp
TEMPLATE = lib
TARGET = ViewerPlugin
QT += qml quick
CONFIG += qt plugin c++11

DESTDIR = ../../imports/Viewer
TARGET = $$qtLibraryTarget($$TARGET)
uri = Viewer

# Input
SOURCES += \
    viewerplugin_plugin.cpp \
    viewer.cpp

HEADERS += \
    viewerplugin_plugin.h \
    viewer.h

DISTFILES += qmldir \
    Viewer.qml \
    ViewerForm.ui.qml \
    components/CListView.qml \
    components/CListViewForm.ui.qml \
    components/CRangeSliderForm.ui.qml \
    components/CSliderForm.ui.qml \
    components/IconButtonForm.ui.qml \
    components/PressAndHoldButton.qml \
    components/TextButton.qml

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

!equals(_PRO_FILE_PWD_, $$OUT_PWD) {
    copy_qmldir.target = $$OUT_PWD/qmldir
    copy_qmldir.depends = $$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/qmldir
    copy_qmldir.commands = $(COPY_FILE) "$$replace(copy_qmldir.depends, /, $$QMAKE_DIR_SEP)" "$$replace(copy_qmldir.target, /, $$QMAKE_DIR_SEP)"
    QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += copy_qmldir
    PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$copy_qmldir.target
}

qmldir.files = qmldir

# Copy the qmldir file to the same folder as the plugin binary
cpqmldir.files = qmldir
cpqmldir.path = $$DESTDIR
COPIES += cpqmldir
```

`qml.qrc`

```js
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file alias="ViewerForm.ui.qml">ViewerForm.ui.qml</file>
    </qresource>

    <qresource prefix="/components">
        <file alias="IconButtonForm.ui.qml">components/IconButtonForm.ui.qml</file>
        <file alias="CRangeSliderForm.ui.qml">components/CRangeSliderForm.ui.qml</file>
        <file alias="CSliderForm.ui.qml">components/CSliderForm.ui.qml</file>
        <file alias="CListView.qml">components/CListView.qml</file>
        <file alias="TextButton.qml">components/TextButton.qml</file>
    </qresource>

    <qresource prefix="/HTML5">
        <file alias="index.html">HTML5/index.html</file>
        <file alias="loader.css">HTML5/loader.css</file>
    </qresource>

    <qresource prefix="/resources">
        <file alias="fontawesome-webfont.ttf">resources/fontawesome-webfont.ttf</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

`qmldir`

```
module Viewer
CListView 1.0 CListView.qml
CListViewForm 1.0 CListViewForm.ui.qml
CRangeSliderForm 1.0 CRangeSliderForm.ui.qml
CSliderForm 1.0 CSliderForm.ui.qml
IconButtonForm 1.0 IconButtonForm.ui.qml
PressAndHoldButton 1.0 PressAndHoldButton.qml
TextButton 1.0 TextButton.qml
plugin ViewerPlugin
```

The components and HTML5 folders exist as described in the `.pro` file. The `viewerplugin_plugin.h/cpp` and `viewer.h/cpp` are the basic files created from the Qt5 wizard for QT Extensions to extend `QQmlExtensionPlugin`.

Below are the files that try to import the ViewerPlugin:

`Client.pro`

```
QT += quick qml serialport core webengine webchannel

CONFIG += c++11 qt
CONFIG += qtquickcompiler

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

!include($${top_srcdir}/common/common.pri) {
    error("Couldn't find common.pri file")
}

!include($${top_srcdir}/qmake-target-platform.pri) {
    error("Couldn't find qmake-target-platform.pri file")
}

!include($${top_srcdir}/qmake-destination-path.pri) {
    error("Couldn't find qmake-destination-path.pri file")
}

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp

DESTDIR = $${top_srcdir}/binaries/$$DESTINATION_PATH
OBJECTS_DIR = $${top_srcdir}/build/$$DESTINATION_PATH/.obj
MOC_DIR = $${top_srcdir}/build/$$DESTINATION_PATH/.moc
RCC_DIR = $${top_srcdir}/build/$$DESTINATION_PATH/.qrc
UI_DIR = $${top_srcdir}/build/$$DESTINATION_PATH/.ui

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Refer to the documentation for the
# deprecated API to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

DISTFILES += \
    Display.qml

# ViewerPlugin needs to be copied to binaries executable directory
CONFIG += file_copies
COPIES += ViewerPlugin
ViewerPlugin.files = $$files($${Viewer}/*)
ViewerPlugin.path = $${DESTDIR}/Viewer

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH = ${top_srcdir}

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =
```

`qml.qrc`

```js
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file alias="Display.qml">Display.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

`main.cpp`

```cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtWebEngine>
#include <QObject>
#include <QMetaObject>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("qtvirtualkeyboard"));
    QGuiApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QtWebEngine::initialize();

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/Display.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
        &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
            if (!obj && url == objUrl)
                QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
        }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

`Display.qml`

```js
import Viewer 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visibility: "Maximized"
    visible: true

    ViewerForm {
        id: viewer
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to move the `.qml` files out of the `components` folder into the root? I think QML is very strict about folder structures. If moving out works, you could try to add another `qmldir` file in the `components` folder and importing `Viewer.Components` (mind the capital)

Comment: Looks like all I needed to do was update the qmldir file to add: `Viewer 1.0 qrc:/Viewer.qml` and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like all I needed to do was update the qmldir file to add: Viewer 1.0 qrc:/Viewer.qml and it works.